# How to find segments of close values in an array?

Tags: arrays

How to implement an algorithm that finds segments of continous close values in an array?

Let's say that we start with the following array:

```
array = [5, 6, 4, 0, 5, 10, 12, 10, 11, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 2]
```

Let's also assume that we will tolerate a "closeness" in each segment of maximum value of 3.

The segments produced would be something like the following:

```
seg[0] = [5, 6, 4]
seg[1] = [0]
seg[2] = [5]
seg[3] = [10, 12, 10, 11]
seg[4] = [4, 3, 2, 3, 2]
seg[5] = [1, 3, 1]
seg[6] = [0, 2]
```

Also, we could allow a "dropout" of, say, maximum one continous value that would fall out of the current segment but would be included if the following values fit in the segment. This would produce something like:

```
seg[0] = [5, 6, 4, 0, 5] //include 0 as a "dropout"
seg[1] = [10, 12, 10, 11]
seg[3] = [4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3] // include 1 as a "dropout"
seg[4] = [1, 3, 1, 0, 2] // include 0 as a "droput"
```

Ideas on how to implement such an algorithm?

Comment: Have you tried to write such an algorithm? Where are you stuck? It should be fairly simple in most languages to write a loop with the appropriate checks

Comment: So element can be repeated as 1 and 3 in seg 3 and 4? Segments usally use for partition - so element can not be repeated in multiple segments

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own take on it. Written in Haxe [(haxe.org)](https://haxe.org).

The `checkDropout()` method checks for "dropouts" of n length, and "normalizes" them away to an average number of the current segment.

```haxe
using Lambda;

class Example {
    static function main() {
        var a:Array<Float> = [5, 6, 4, 0, 5, 10, 12, 10, 11, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 2];

        // Segment value tolerance of 2
        // Dropout max length of 3
        var segmentor = new Segmentor(2, 3);

        // Callback for displaying result
        segmentor.displayResult = (r, v) -> {
            trace('-------------------------------------');
            trace('value added: ' + v);
            trace('result: ' + r);
        }

        // Feed the segmentor with the example values
        a.map(i -> segmentor.addNumber(i));

        // var result = [
        //  [5, 6, 4, 5, 5],
        //  [10, 12, 10, 11],
        //  [4, 3, 2, 3, 2],
        //  [1, 3, 1],
        //  [0, 2]
        // ];
    }
}

class Segmentor {
    public function new(valueSpan:Int = 2, dropoutLength:Int = 1) {
        this.valueSpan = valueSpan;
        this.dropoutLength = dropoutLength;
        this.result = [];
        this.result.push([]);
    }

    var dropoutLength:Int = null;
    var valueSpan:Int = null;

    public var result(default, null):Array<Array<Float>>;

    public function addNumber(v:Float) {
        this.processNumber(v);
    }

    function processNumber(v:Float) {
        var current = this.result[this.result.length - 1];
        if (current.length == 0) {
            current.push(v);
        } else if (fitIn(current, v) || this.checkDropout(v)) {
            var current2 = this.result[this.result.length - 1];
            current2.push(v);
        } else {
            this.result.push([v]);
        }
        this.displayResult(this.result, v);
    }

    dynamic public function displayResult(result:Array<Array<Float>>, valueAdded:Float) {}

    function checkDropout(v:Float):Bool {
        if (this.result.length <= 1)
            return false;

        var last = this.result[this.result.length - 1];
        if (last.length <= this.dropoutLength) {
            var prev = this.result[this.result.length - 2];

            if (fitIn(prev, v)) {
                var mid = mid(prev);
                var newLast = [for (i in 0...last.length) mid];
                newLast.map(n -> prev.push(n));
                this.result.pop();
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    function fitIn(a:Array<Float>, v:Float):Bool {
        var max = a.fold((c, v) -> Math.max(v, c), a[0]);
        var min = a.fold((c, v) -> Math.min(v, c), a[0]);
        var fit = ((max - v <= this.valueSpan) && (v - min <= this.valueSpan));
        return fit;
    }

    function mid(a:Array<Float>) {
        var max = a.fold((c, v) -> Math.max(v, c), a[0]);
        var min = a.fold((c, v) -> Math.min(v, c), a[0]);
        return min + (max - min) / 2;
    }
}
```